# Are the returned files streamed via the server or directly to the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i return a path via a ASP.NET MVC Controller like this.

```
public ActionResult GetImage()
{          
     return base.File(path, "image/png");            
}
```

Will the File streamed over the iis server to my browser, or can the browser access the path direct and download it on his own?

I want to prevent the double streaming of a file (filelocation->iis->browser)

Another question:
Can the file acces multiple times, or is it locked after the first access?

Comment: "i return a path"...This code returns the file data itself, not a path, as far as I can see. So yes your MVC application gets the data from the disk, and streams it to the browser. And of course IIS is involved, since it served the request. But if the browser already knew the URL of the image and requested it directly, the image data would still be taken from the disk and streamed back to the browser via IIS. IIS is the webserver and will serve all HTTP requests coming from the browser. There's no "direct" access to the server's disk, everything goes through the webserver.

Comment: And yes, a browser can request a file from the server as many times as it like, unless you write some code to limit the number of requests or something. It's not clear from your question whether you just want to get a better understanding of the technology, or you have some underlying problem which you're trying to solve?

Comment: just wanted to understand the way the file go, thx.